# Produtório de uma função

Tags: python, python-2.7

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe alguma comando para realizar o produtório de uma função no Python. Estou criando uma função para fazer o produtório de outra função.

```
def fx(a, v, t):
    return ( (t[3]/exp(t[2]-(t[1]/v)))*(a/exp(t[2]-(t[1]/v)))^(t[3]-1)*exp(-(a/exp(t[2]-(t[1]/v)))^t[3]) )

def L(x, v, t):
    return (numpy.prod(fx(a=A,v=V,t)) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimenta o seguinte:

```
from functools import reduce # caso utilizes python 3
import operator

reduce(operator.mul, (2, 3, 4), 1)
```

Sendo 2, 3 e 4 os números a multiplicar. Um resposta semelhante pode ser vista [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595374/whats-the-python-function-like-sum-but-for-multiplication-prod).

Comment: Muito obrigada!